# Get column names using jaydebeapi

Tags: python, jaydebeapi

How can i do the following in jaydebeapi ?

```
#In Java
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(0) ## basically i am interested with this part
```

Answer (score 9):

As JayDeBeApi implements the DB-API, check [PEP 249's .description attribute](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description).
This should work:

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect(...)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2')
column_name = curs.description[0][0]
assert column_name == 'a', column_name
```